# Installing Ubuntu 20.04.2 Live ISO on a Dell R730 with Perc Raid controller

Tags: server, 20.04

It always blows up during the install.  configuring installed system

```
   running '/snap/bin/subiquity.sub
   running '/snap/bin/subiquity.sub
   curtin command apt-config
   curtin command in-target
```

I did F10 on boot and install Other OS via the Lifecycle controller

Any ideas?

Comment: I've been successful with a Dell RAID controller, but you need to be a lot more specific with what you did if you want any help.  "blows up" isn't helpful at all (unless it really did blow up!).  Is this a new system?  If it is, you need to go through the BIOS to assemble the hard drives according to the RAID configuration of your choice.  I presume you've done this?  You need edit your post to list the things that you've done...

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific on what raid controller MODEL you are using. I assume you've built an array and made it bootable in the controller bios and the controller is bootable? Is it an actual HARDWARE Raid controller or a softraid controller or HBA? How recent is the controller bios? I'm assuming it's likely an LSI oem controller as I think they made most of the Perc controllers but knowing which one would help.

Comment: A lot more specific?  You don't know much about Dell PowerEdge servers do you?   It's okay.

It's the Perc-2 hardware raid controller with 2GB of write back cache with an external battery.

Well... I checked my invoice and I'm incorrect... I dont' know much it would seem.

H730P Mini RAID Controller 2GB Cache

Comment: I just flashed the BIOS to the latest version (2020 I think was the year).  It's older hardware no doubt.

Comment: H730P firmware is 25.5.8.0001 from December 2020.

Comment: Dell PowerEdge R730 16-Bay Server with 2.5" Bays

- 2x 2.60Ghz E5-2690v4 14 Core Processors - Total of 28x Cores

- 16x 16GB PC4-2133P RAM - Total of 256GB Memory

- 16x 1.2TB 10K SAS 2.5'' 12G - Total Storage of 12.0TB

- 2x 1100W Platinum Power Supplies with 2x Power Cords

- H730P Mini RAID Controller 2GB Cache

- iDRAC8 Express

- Network Interface: 2x 10GB SFP + 2x 1GB RJ-45

Comment: Thank you. I looked up the card, shows it compatible with Red Hat and Suse so one would think it would work just fine with Ubuntu. Have you tried booting to a live CD? If you do you could run: lspci -vv and see if Ubuntu is showing a driver for it. 

Also when I have tried to install Ubuntu server over an previous install I've had to delete all the partitions first. Perhaps give that a try.

Comment: It is not compatible with Red Hat or Suse.  Red Hat 7.2 or newer requires special H730P drivers be installed which are not compatible with Red Hat 8+

so that is incorrect.

Comment: Dell's website has H730P drivers for Red Hat 7.5 but not sure how to install those or if they are compatible with Ubuntu 20.04